# How to transform an arbitrary case identifier to pascal case in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Right now the vscode is able to transform any identifier to the following cases but not pascal case:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yq58B.png)

How to add pascal case to the supported cases?

tried ctr+shift+p and then typed "transform to pascal case"
expected to see the "transform to pascal case" in the supported cases

Comment: create a combined command to: transform to camelCase, go to word begin, select 1 char, transform to Uppercase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: a commit has recently been added that enables a pascal case transform - [Add PascalCase to CaseActions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/0a0f196666c687e0dd0642411a70ba0e7f9cb1c1) .  It may make it into the next update this week - vscode v1.87.

The new command is

```
editor.transformToPascalcase : "Transform to Pascal Case"
```

---

Snippets do have a `pascalcase` transform so you could make either these keybindings:

```
// with cursor at the end of the identifier

{
  "key": "alt+p alt+c",        // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "runCommands",
  "args": {
    "commands": [
      "cursorHomeSelect",       
      {
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "args": {
          "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(.*)/${1:/pascalcase}/}"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},

// you select the identifier first for the below keybinding

{
  "key": "alt+p alt+c",          // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "args": {
    "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(.*)/${1:/pascalcase}/}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported ATM.
But there's a tracking issue on [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/187387) to whether add this feature.
Upvote this github issue in order to vscode devs consider this as a feature request.

Comment: Yup it will be cool if this is a supported option and not using any key binding or installing an external extension.